# Installing Boot Manager on external HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, mbr

I have installed Ubuntu on a 500 GB partition in a 1TB external HDD. Setting boot order to USB first didn't work.

Edit : I have used Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 (beta on 22.04.2020) My Laptop has BIOS not UEFI

I figured out that Ubuntu boot manger had been installed on my computer (not external hard disk where I have installed Ubuntu).

Now, everytime i need to boot into Ubuntu, i have to enter BIOS and tell my computer to boot Ubuntu(and not windows, installed in the internal hd). This also means my hard drive can't be plugged in to any other pc to use the installed Ubuntu system.

Please tell me how i can rectify this. Thanks.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Also UEFI or BIOS? How you correctly install boot loader to external drive varies greatly. And if wanting to use with other systems, they  also need to be in same boot mode.

Comment: Hi K7AAY i have added the required information. Thanks

Comment: If BIOS you just need to re-install BIOS boot loaders to correct drives. You can boot into Ubuntu and install grub to the MBR of sdb or whatever external drive is seen as. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System You can use your Windows repair disk and run fixMBR command or Boot-Repair and it can install a Windows type boot loader, syslinux to MBR of internal drive to boot Windows. Use Advanced Mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Hi. After using boot-repair i am able to boot into my hard disk in legacy boot mode only not uefi boot mode. For uefi i have to still depend on the grub that's installed on my internal HDD. Sorry for wrong info given previously. Please tell me how i can boot into the external HDD using uefi also. Thanks